# Removing the rectangle from top of web page

Tags: html, css

This one is taking a lot of time as I can not understand the problem associated with.I am still a newcomer to CSS and don't understand the problem completely .

This is the piece of code from CSS which controls the background of the web page

```
#intro1 {
    height:1000px;
    background: #000 url('../innerimages/slide4.jpg');
    background-position:center 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

at this point the web page looks something like this [image]

now if i change the color to fff.i.e

```
#intro1 {
    height:1000px;
    background: #fff url('../innerimages/slide4.jpg');
    background-position:center 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

the page looks like this [image]

and this is the html part

```
<div id="verticalScrollArea" style="display: block; top: -65.27584886649873px;">
    <section id="intro1" data-navigation-tag="About SVP 69" style="display: block;        background-position: 100% 44.8228px;">
          <div id="intro1content" class="content" style="display: block; margin-top: 61.86937866666666px;">
        <div class="contentData"> <div class="background">SOME TEXT <br>
              <a href="http://69svp.in/about.html"><img src="./69 SVP_files/know-more.png"></a> 
</div> </div>
        <div class="scrollDown"> <span>SOME TEXT</span> <img src="./69 SVP_files/scroll-down.png"></div>
      </div>
        </section>
```

What I want is the image to be in full screen .I can not figure it out where am I going wrong in removing the back/white strip ?
How it can be removed

[image]

Comment: did you use firebug or chrome to inspect the page?

Comment: better share a website link, then you can get a quick result..

Comment: kheema pandey have a look at this site http://69svp.in/

am just trying to remove the black strip (same one on the top) and to change the background with my own image.I removed the other things but black one is  hurting me

Comment: thanks for sharing the link. The URL you have given are you talking about the white line at the top?

Comment: Kheema Pandey what am trying is like the complete thing to be removed ,all the address customization everything so that ,the image is displayed completely.I want the white line black strip everything to be removed

assuming like in the screen short i have attached there will not be the black/white strip ,and the image starting from the top left.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `margin-top` from your `#intro1`'s `inline CSS`, you can use `padding-top` instead of `margin`

Comment: No change it still displays the same old result.white strip for white and black strip for black.

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle or something else?

Comment: I was unable to replicate the feature in js fiddle u can check this one http://69svp.in/.This is the site upon which am trying to customize.

Comment: you have to give equal value in verticalScrollArea's top in minus and intro1Content's margin-top,

Comment: can u explain a bit it was confusing for me "verticalScrollArea's top in minus and intro1Content's margin-top"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by this line of code:

```
<div id="intro1content" class="content" style="display: block; margin-top: 61.86937866666666px;">
```

Specifically, the margin-top that you are applying inline is causing this colored strip to show. Just remove this inline css for margin-top.

Comment: With this change the result is what something I can not work with. I have two sections and what it does is that ,it removes the first section completely and jumps to 2nd one directly,with the black strip acquiring some around 25 % of the screen

Comment: if you just remove the margin-top line?

Comment: No change either white for white and black for black

Comment: Could you provide us a link to your webpage so we might inspect it? Or a fiddle link with the images?

Comment: Am a new comer I tried to create the js fiddle but was unable to replicate the feature u can check this site  http://69svp.in/
It is the same reference source upon which i am trying to customize.

Comment: Ya I still stand by my answer, I can't seem to replicate your problem unless you have an actual example that I can inspect. What do you mean by it removes the first section completely when you remove the margin?

Answer (score 0):

There in this ID:

remove the margin-top: 61.86937866666666px;

Comment: I have tried already with previous suggestions it does not work

Answer (score 0):

[image]I don't find any problem with the header section. Only one glitch I saw that a white strange line was appearing. for better explanation check the screenshot.[image]

let me know this is what you want?

okay do you want like this? check the update screenshot?

Comment: kheema no plz look my screen short once more u have still the logo the phone no the black strip I don't want that ,I need everything to be gone.Just compare your with mine hope u can get the diff.I have added the menu and sub menu actually its the customized one not what is present in the website.I have removed that part the menu and submenu from website ,but that black strip I was unable to remove.

Comment: Kheema thanks for your patience ad help.I have added a new screenshort u can check  that.The menu in my screenshort is the one added by me.I was able to remove the menu (Your page ,amenities,gallery etc),but they are upon a black rectangular strip,that is what I was unable to remove and still wondering how to remove ,hope u got my problem completely